# Swift - If Statement Won't Run

Tags: swift

My `if` statement won't run. I don't know why it won't run.

```
@IBOutlet weak var Email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!
@IBAction func Login(_ sender: AnyObject) {      
    let email = Email.text
    let password = Password.text

    let postURL = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/app/signin.php?email" + email! + "&password" + password!)!
    var postRequest = URLRequest(url: postURL)
    postRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    postRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    postRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let httpBODY = postRequest.httpBody
    let mail : Data = email!.data(using: .utf8)!
    if httpBODY == mail { // Error is happening right here
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoggedOn")
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        } else {
            let title = "Wrong!"
            let message = "Incorrect username or bad Password."

            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
            alertController.addAction(OKAction)

            var alertWindow : UIWindow!
            alertWindow = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController.init()
            alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
            alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
            alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Expected: The Button will get the email and password and send a request to the url. If the email and password are valid, it will display the email. If the email is equal to the HTTP body, then it will redirect to the LoggedOn Storyboard.

What's happening: The Button will get the email and password and send a request to the url. If the email and password are valid, it will display the email. If the email is equal to the HTTP body, it does nothing.

The Storyboard is not connected to the LoggedOn Storyboard. I don't know if it needs to be or not. Could someone please help me figure out whats going on?

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint to see if that function is called, and what the value of "httpBODY" is, when you expect it to equal mail?

Comment: Yes, if the body of the http request is equal to the email, then redirect to LoggedOn Storyboard.

Comment: So the issue was that the Op wanted to use Alamofire to make this POST request but was not actually using it...